# GITLAB relative links to parent directory not working in README.md file

Tags: gitlab

I am writing a simple README.md for a Gitlab project. I just want to create a link to 2 dirs up. So use this

`Click [here](../..)`

It's going to the wrong directory and jumping to a 404 page. I have investigated and it appears relative links actually work but for some reason it's starting from a different page than the one I'm currently on. For simplicity I'll show just the end of the URL as it's fairly long

This is where I am
`platform-general-utils/-/tree/main/maintenance-mode/roles/maintenance_mode_head`

This is where it seems to think I am and where it bases all relative URLs from
`platform-general-utils/-/blob/main/`

I can kind of work around this by using this relative link but it's very cumbersome and I presume prone to breaking in the future.
`../../tree/main/maintenance-mode`

Any fix for this?

Comment: If you're going to use relative links in the Readme, you should make it work for the local git repository. You can add a note to say the links don't work in the UI unless the user is viewing it from a specific part of the UI.